# create class dynamically in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, codedom

I'm using **EntityFramework** `CodeFirst` and i want to create my model and `ViewMode` s classes, **programmatically**. so i used `C# CodeDom` to create Model and view models classes . and i could create them in a cs files by the same **namespace**... and like you see below, i added my class namespaces in `dbContext`... and it works perfectly much!.

```
    public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{

    public MyDBContext() : base("MyCon")
    {

        Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDBContext>());
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
        var theList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                  .Where(t => t.Namespace == "FullDynamicWepApp.Data.Domins")
                  .ToList();
        foreach (var item in theList)
        {
            entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(item)
                           .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

next ...when i'm finished adding cs classes programmatically (by **C#** `CodeDOM`) i had to **rebuild** my project for **include** the new cs files, into my project ..so i built my project programmatically like this:

```
          if (ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects(@"D:\imanSal\SmlpeApp\SmlpeApp\SmlpeApp.csproj").Count == 0)
            {
                p = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(@"D:\imanSal\SmlpeApp\SmlpeApp\SmlpeApp.csproj");
            }
            else
            {
                p = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects(@"D:\imanSal\SmlpeApp\SmlpeApp\SmlpeApp.csproj").First();
            }





            p.RemoveItem(BuildProj.GetProjectItem(p, outputFileName + this.ClassName + ".cs"));

            p.Save();

            p.Build();
```

**but my problem is this:** i cant use my new classes(`ViewModels` and `Models`...) until i stop and run my project again. this is my last problem that I'm looking for a solution for that, for more than a week :( and i couldn't find any solution yet. what must i do ? how can i create a class at run time and use it at run time to ...without "stop and run" my project again!?

Comment: How is this different from this question of yours? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055606/creating-class-at-run-time-and-use-it-without-reloading-project

Comment: actually i need the answer. not Inspector

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. actually creating class by `codeDOM` will not solve my problem. i needed  to create a `dll` in iis and create my class inside that, usind `CSharpCodeProvider()` like this:

```
      CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = "Per.dll";
        CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, "public class PersonVM{ " + "public int id{get;set;}" +
            "public string Name{get;set;}" + " }");

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Per.dll");
        var type = assembly.GetType("PersonVM");
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
        return View(obj);
```